# error when user entering dot in python input

Tags: python, python-3.x

im wondering why is

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    .
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

coming when i execute following script and including dot in input.

```
answer = input('enter 1: ')
if answer == 1:
    print('nice')
else:
    print('please enter "1"')
    return
```

I have been wondering this pretty long, and now im trying to ask here if someone could help me.
So i can't include dots or anything else that basic letters and numbers my input.
I thought there could be easy way to find this thing out.
There is other code i need to fix below, with same error.

```
email = str(input('required* Your mail: '))
print('your mail is : ' + email)
```

now, it needs to include dot and at mark.

Comment: `input()` returns a string, doesn't it? `== 1` will not work as expected, IMHO

Comment: How are you executing your script? It thinks the `.` is python syntax, not user input

Comment: For me, using a dot as input is fine. It seems you have a dot somewhere in your code (or in an imported file)

Comment: You must have a dot as a typo somewhere in your *source code* (nothing to do with your user input). Check your source code. After you fix that, you probably want to fix the comparison so it compares a string to a string, not an integer: `answer == '1':` Because comparing a string to an integer 1 is always going to return False, so you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: @smci: which loop?

Comment: Are you perhaps running this on python2? `input` tries to parse the user input as Python syntax in Python2

Comment: @ThomasWeller: the code excerpt is clearly incomplete and comes from a function (it has a return statement), often input-validation code runs in a loop, or that fn is called in a loop. (We can't know unless the OP posts full code)

Answer (score 0):

The code here seems ok, except for the fact you're using return without a function.

And the code wouldn't work when I put I type 1, because you need to cast the var "aswer".

The code should be like this:

```
answer = int(input('enter 1: '))
if answer == 1:
    print('nice')
else:
    print('please enter "1"')
```

Comment: Conversion to `int()` can cause exceptions. Comparing to `"1"` seems more robist here

Comment: @ThomasWeller, You're right, but the string will accept any entry, I think it depends on what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a **string**  and you are checking if is this a **number**, that is your error, so if you want to ask every time if the answer is wrong you could do this:

```
while True:
    answer = input('enter 1: ')
    if answer == "1":
        print('nice')
        break
    else:
        print('please enter "1"')
```

Comment: just a tip: `correct = answer == "1"` and then if you say `if correct: ... else: ...`